# Proving the limit of lipschitz, complex-analytic function is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Suppose that a sequence of analytic functions is locally Lipschitz in an open connected set $D$ of the complex plane. (That is, for all $z\in D$, there is a constant $L$ such that $|f_n(z_1)-f_n(z_2)|\leq L|z_1-z_2|$ if $z_1,z_2$ are in a neighborhood of $z$.)

I want to show that $f(z)$ must also be analytic, and moreover $f_n'(z)\to f'(z)$, where $f(z)$ is the **pointwise** limit of $f_n$.

I think I can show that $f$ is continuous using a $\epsilon/3$ type argument (ie split up $|f_n(z)-f(z)|$ using the triangle inequality), but I'm not sure how this shows analyticity of the  function $f$. I would really like to say that we in fact have *uniform* convergence, but I'm not sure if the condition given is strong enough to prove that.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It would be a bit clearer if you said that you have a family of complex-analytic functions $(f_n)_n$ that is equi-lipschitz on some domain $D$ and that converge pointwise to some function $f$ on $D$. You are wishing for uniform convergence. While that is in general not true, it is along a subsequence (which is sufficient in this case) by the Arzela-Ascoli theorem.

Comment: the idea is that passing to the limit $z_2 \to z_1$ after division shows that the derivatives of $f_n$ are uniformly bounded by $L$, from here it immediately follows that $f_n'=g_n$ form a normal family; but since $f_n$ converges point-wise and a sub-sequence of  $g_n$ converges normally to some $g$ the usual arguments show that the corresponding sub-sequence of $f_n$ converges normally to $f$ which is differentiable and $f'=g$; from here all is clear as then $g_n$ can have only one limit etc

Comment: @SeverinSchraven If we don't have uniform continuity, do we at least have something like local-uniform continuity? ie around each point there is a neighborhood that converges uniformly?

Comment: @Conrad Can you elaborate a little bit? I'm not sure what you mean by a normal family and the argument of subsequences

Comment: @MikeAinsel Sorry, I meant uniform convergence (clearly it is uniformly continuous as it it is lipschitz). Local uniform convergence along a subsequence is exactly what I am claiming. However, having uniform convergence along a subsequence is enough to get analyticity of the limiting function $f$.

Comment: a normal family of analytic functions is one for which every sequence has a subsequence that converges normally (uniformly on compact subsets); Montel's theorem says that a family that is uniformly bounded on some domain is normal (essentially follows from Cauchy and the usual Arzela-Ascoli type of arguments), so the sequence of derivatives $g_n$ is normal so every subsequence of it has a locally uniform convergent sub-subsequence so to speak; but then if a subsequence of $g_n$ converges to $g$ normally, $g$ is analytic and since $f_n$ converges pointwise it follows $f'=g$, so $g$ is unique

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I think I'm getting a little lost, unfortunately. Are we saying that *local lipschitz* gives $f_n\to f$ *locally uniformly* (as in, for all $z\in D$, there is a neighborhood $U_z$ such that $f_n\to f$ uniformly)?

Comment: What I am saying is if the family $(f_n)_n$ is equi-lipschitz on some compact space $D$ and $(f_n)_n$ converges pointwise, then there exists a subsequence $(f_{n_k})_k$ which converges uniformly on $D$ (this follows from the Arzela-Ascoli) theorem. Conrad mentions that if $(f_n)_n$ consists of analytic functions, then we do not need equi-lipschitz to begin with, but bounded is sufficient (this is Montel's theorem). He applies Montel's theorem to the derivatives $(f_n')_n$ which now also admit some subsequence that converge uniformly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall Montel's theorem. It says if $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is a domain and $(f_n)_n$ is a family of complex-analytic functions $f_n : U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ that is locally uniformly bounded (i.e for any compact $D\subseteq U$ there exists a constant $C_D$ such that $\sup_{n} \Vert f_n \Vert_{L^\infty(D)}<C_D)$ we have that there exists a subsequence $(f_{n_k})_k$ that converges uniformly on compact subsets of $U$.

Now we show that $(f_n)_n$ and $(f_n')_n$ are both locally uniformly bounded if $(f_n)_n$ is locally equi-lipschitz (this means locally we can find an upper bound for the lipschitz constant of all functions in our family).

It is clear that $\vert f_n'\vert$ on $D$ is bounded by the Lipschitz constant of $f_n$ on $D$. Thus, locally equi-lipschitz implies that $(f_n')_n$ is locally uniformly bounded. On the other hand, if we fix some compact $D\subseteq U$, and some point $z_0\in D$, then we get
$$ \vert f_n(z) \vert \leq \vert f_n(z_0) \vert + \vert f_n(z)-f_n(z_0) \vert 
\leq \sup_{n} \vert f_n(z_0) \vert + \text{diam}(D) \Vert f_n'\Vert_{L^\infty(D)}.$$
As $(f_n(z_0))_n$ converges and $(f_n')_n$ is locally uniformly bounded, we get that $(f_n)_n$ is locally uniformly bounded too.

In particular, we can now use Montel's theorem and pick a subsequence $(f_{n_k})_k$ and some functions $h,g$ such that $(f_{n_k})_k$ converges locally uniformly to $h$ and $(f_{n_k}')_k$ converges locally uniformly to $g$. However, as $(f_n)_n$ converges pointwise to $f$, we get that $h=f$. Also, as $f$ is locally the uniform limit of complex-analytic functions, we get that $f$ is complex-analytic.

As $(f_{n_k})_k$ converges locally uniformly to $f$ and $(f_{n_k}')_k$ converges locally uniformly to $g$ one can use the standard argument to show that $g=f'$. Namely, fix $z_0, z\in U$ and path $\gamma$ that connects $z_0, z$. As the path is compact, we have that $(f_{n_k})_k$,$(f_{n_k}')_k$ converges uniformly on $\gamma$ and hence, we obtain
$$ f(z) = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} f_{n_k}(z) = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \left( f_{n_k}(z_0)+ \int_\gamma f_{n_k}'(\tau) d\tau \right) = f(z_0) + \int_\gamma g(\tau) d\tau. $$
Taking a derivative in $z$ yields $f'(z) = g(z)$ (by the fundamental theorem of calculus).

Finally, we can now start with any subsequence $(f_{n_m})_m$ and find a subsequence $(f_{n_{m_\ell}})_\ell$ such that $(f_{n_{m_\ell}})_\ell$ converges locally uniformly to $f$ and $(f_{n_{m_\ell}}')_\ell$ converges locally uniformly to $f'$. This means, that if you fix with some $z\in U$, then there exists for every subsequence $(f_{n_m}'(z))_m$ a subsequence $(f_{n_{m_\ell}}')_\ell$ that converges to $f'(z)$. However, this implies that $(f'_n(z))_n$ converges to $f'(z)$, which is what we wanted to show.

Comment: Thank you! The extra detail really helped! Cheers, Mike

Comment: @MikeAinsel Glad I could help.